# Inheriting constructor and template alias

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Q{ int i; };

namespace detail
{
  template<typename T, typename U> struct base
  {
    Q q;
    base( Q const& qq ):q(qq){ printf("q"); }
  };
}

template <typename T> struct vec : public detail::base<T, vec<T>>
{
  using detail::base<T, vec<T>>::base; // All: OK

  using Z = typename detail::base<T, vec<T>>;

  using Z::base; // GCC: OK, MSVC: OK, Clang: ERR
  using typename Z::base; // GCC: OK, MSVC: ERR, Clang: OK
};

int main()
{
  Q q{2};
  vec<float> v( q );
}
```

If I inherit the CTORs of the base class without any proxy alias/typedef, it compiles on all 3 major compilers, but it can be verbose with compley templated base classes (and it is, hence the question). When using Z, GCC is very liberal, but MSVC and Clang disagree, and I tend to give MSVC the credit. With typename, MSVC says Z::base is not a typename, and it really isn't.

Which one is conforming code that uses Z?

Comment: `using Z::Z;` is allowed on all 3 compilers.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That is a handy solution to the problem. If somebody however cares to clean it up, which one is wrong and in what way, and why do the compilers react so differently? The fix for now is in place.